# IOS6.0 UIWebView Scheme of Tel:

Tags: objective-c, ios

I found an `UIWebview` Change between `IOS 5.0` and `IOS 6.0`

If You use `[UIWebview loadRequest]` for Callout a number and give a url string like 
`@"tel://02-1234567,123"`.

It's working fine in `IOS5.0` but NOT in `IOS 6.0`

I try to override this function

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

I found My Request String become `"file://tel://02-1234567,123"`.

The Scheme I Got is `@"file://"` not `@"tel://"` and I can't make a phone call.

If I simply use a number without extension like `@"tel://02-1234567"`,It's working fine.

In Some reason I couldn't say,I can't use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` OpenUrl to make a phone call.

Does any one have the same problem?

Comment: Does this only happen coming from a web view? I can still create a tel:// URL myself and open it without getting file:// prepended to it.

Comment: Did you solve it ? Can u share?

Comment: Yes,I solve this.Thanks thom_ek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI is incorrect. Correct one is "tel:1234567890". [See RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966).
Also, check [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).